# How to change default color of pie chart series label text using achart engine?

Tags: android, pie-chart, achartengine

I want to create pie chart with some values . I created pie chart like this

[image]

Now i want to change label text color and reduce gap/space between pie and legend. How can i do this? Can anybody help me to resolve this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change the labels color this way:

```
renderer.setLabelsColor(Color.BLUE);
```

You can make the pie chart bigger which would get it closer to the legend this way:

```
renderer.setScale(1.25f);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
     change the following things:=  

     // set up gradient paints for series...
    GradientColor gp0 = new GradientColor(Color.YELLOW, Color.rgb(2, 2, 64));
    GradientColor gp1 = new GradientColor(Color.WHITE, Color.rgb(0, 64, 0));
    GradientColor gp2 = new GradientColor(Color.YELLOW, Color.rgb(64, 0, 0));
    renderer.setSeriesPaintType(0, gp0);
    renderer.setSeriesPaintType(1, gp1);
    renderer.setSeriesPaintType(2, gp2);
```